# Non Autonomous Difference Equations

Tags: linear-algebra, convergence-divergence, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, recurrence-relations

What are some of the textbooks/research papers which explore the limiting behaviour of difference equations with time dependent coefficients? Where can I read about necessary and/or sufficient conditions which ensure that such systems converge?